# How to disable nav tabs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the html part

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#fragment-1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-3">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab-pane">
    <div id="fragment-1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-2">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-3">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to disable the tabs and its tab content.

I disabled tab by adding class disable but also when I click on it, it displays the content of the active tab.

How to do it using javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 $('#tabs').tabs({ event: '' });
```

or

```
 $('#tabs').tabs({ event: 'change' });
```

Answer (score 0):

See this url might help.

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-disabled
It takes "disabled" as option